# How to push specific branch to ftp server with git-ftp

Tags: git, ftp, git-branch, git-push, git-ftp

### Context

I'm using [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/tree/releases/0.9.x) to upload my git files to my ftp server. In git, I have 2 branches: `development` and `production`. When I want to upload the `development` branch, I commit, push and then upload with the command:

```
git ftp push --user <user> --passwd <passwd> <ftp-server>/development
```

---

### Problem

Let's say that I want to push my `production` branch into the `production` folder of my server, how could I tell git-ftp that it's this branch I want to push, and not my development one? I couldn't find an option for that in the [man](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/releases/0.9.x/man/git-ftp.1.md). Example :

```
git ftp push --user <user> --passwd <passwd> <ftp-server>/production --branch production
```

Answer (score 4):

Refer to git-ftp scopes

https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp/blob/master/man/git-ftp.1.md

There is an example of how to config a production/testing environment

```
$ git config git-ftp.testing.url ftp.testing.com:8080/foobar-path
$ git config git-ftp.testing.password simp3l

$ git config git-ftp.production.user manager
$ git config git-ftp.production.url live.example.com
```

you should use

```
git ftp push -s production --branch production
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand - git-ftp works only with file states (files itself) - not with git branches, so your net switch/checkout to push needing data related to some git-ftp scope)